No source map for contract ArbitrageTest
I am attempting to debug the following contract:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity 0.8.26;

import {Test} from "forge-std/Test.sol";
import {console} from "../lib/forge-std/src/console.sol";
import {Arbitrage} from "../src/Arbitrage.sol";
import {Dex} from "../src/Dex.sol";
import {XToken} from "../src/XToken.sol";
import {Vault} from "../src/Vault.sol";
import {MockFlashLoanProvider} from "../src/MockFlashLoanProvider.sol";

contract ArbitrageTest is Test {
    uint swapAmount;
    Arbitrage public arbitrage;
    Dex public dex1;
    Dex public dex2;
    XToken public xtoken;
    MockFlashLoanProvider public mfp;
    Vault public vault;

    function setUp() public {
        console.log("******Begin Setup******");
        mfp = new MockFlashLoanProvider();
        vault = new Vault();
        dex1 = new Dex("1");
        dex2 = new Dex("2");
        xtoken = new XToken(0);
        // If tokens are being transferred between dexes or other addresses, ensure they are also approved
        xtoken.approve(address(dex1), type(uint256).max);
        xtoken.approve(address(dex2), type(uint256).max);
        xtoken.approve(address(mfp), type(uint256).max);

        xtoken.supply(address(dex1), 25000);
        xtoken.supply(address(dex2), 5000);
        xtoken.supply(address(mfp), 1000000);
        dex1.setTokenPrice(address(xtoken),125);
        dex2.setTokenPrice(address(xtoken),100);
        uint256 dex1BalanceOf = xtoken.balanceOf(address(dex1));
        uint256 dex2BalanceOf = xtoken.balanceOf(address(dex2));
        uint256 dex1ValueOfTokens = dex1.valueOfTokens(address(xtoken));
        uint256 dex2ValueOfTokens = dex2.valueOfTokens(address(xtoken));
        uint256 dex1TokenPrice = dex1.getTokenPrice(address(xtoken));
        uint256 dex2TokenPrice = dex2.getTokenPrice(address(xtoken));

        console.log("dex1TokenPrice", dex1TokenPrice);
        console.log("dex2TokenPrice", dex2TokenPrice);

        if (dex1TokenPrice > dex2TokenPrice) {
            arbitrage = new Arbitrage(address(mfp),address(dex2), address(dex1), address(xtoken));
            swapAmount = arbitrage.findMinimuBalance(dex2BalanceOf, dex1BalanceOf);
        } else {
            arbitrage = new Arbitrage(address(mfp),address(dex1), address(dex2), address(xtoken));
            swapAmount = arbitrage.findMinimuBalance(dex1BalanceOf, dex2BalanceOf);
        }
        // Ensure arbitrage contract is approved to transfer tokens
        xtoken.approve(address(arbitrage), type(uint256).max); // Approve max amount for arbitrage contract

        console.log("dex1ValueOfTokens:", dex1ValueOfTokens);
        console.log("dex2ValueOfTokens:", dex2ValueOfTokens);
        mfp.transferToken(address(xtoken), address(arbitrage), 100);
        console.log("dex1.valueOfTokens(address(xtoken)):", dex1.valueOfTokens(address(xtoken)));
        console.log("dex2.valueOfTokens(address(xtoken)):", dex2.valueOfTokens(address(xtoken)));
        console.log("******End Setup******");
    }

    function test_arbitrage() public {
        console.log("Before swap");
        // Use vm.record() to start tracking the transaction
        //vm.record();

        // Perform the arbitrage operation (transaction)
        uint256 gasBefore = gasleft();
        try arbitrage.checkAndExecuteArbitrage(swapAmount) {
            console.log("Arbitrage executed successfully");
        } catch {
            console.log("Arbitrage execution failed");
        }
        uint256 gasUsed = gasBefore - gasleft();
        console.log("Gas used in transaction:", gasUsed);
        console.log("After swap");
        console.log("xtoken.balanceOf(address(arbitrage)):", xtoken.balanceOf(address(arbitrage)));
        console.log("xtoken.balanceOf(address(dex1)):", xtoken.balanceOf(address(dex1)));
        console.log("xtoken.balanceOf(address(dex2)):", xtoken.balanceOf(address(dex2)));
    }
}

forge --version
forge 0.2.0 (be451fb 2024-09-11T00:20:35.367236373Z)

Any ides how I can fix this?


You don't need to fix anything, because when you're debugging a test function using the following command:
forge test --debug <TEST_FUNCTION>

It traces its call and list all the OPCODES involved in the call. And, while iterating through the OPCODES, some of them are Contract's Own OPCODES, while others are System-level OPCODES.
So, for the Contract's Own OPCODES, you'll get the corresponding line or portion of the source code mapped to those OPCODES in the Contract call section.
Whereas, for the System-level OPCODES, you'll get "No source map for contract ContractName" output in the Contract call section.
